# how to access gmail account in android application for my project?

Tags: android, api, gmail

I want to make an android app in which the user have to register and Login with his/her Gmail account and after registering a confirmation mail must be sent on user's Gmail account??
I referred to the developer page of Google but i got confused as this is my first project.
I haven't tried the Google APIs.Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Google+ Sign-in for Android

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

There are also two other Java libraries that you might consider for this purpose:

https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java